# All methods under system.web.security cannot work if adding a linq to sql to the project

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I used VS2012 to create a default web application. If I add a linq to sql, all the methods under system.web. security cannot work. I did not make any changes to the default application. Can any one help me? Thanks a lot!!

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Membership.GetUserNameByEmail("test@gmail.com");

        }
    }
}
```

When I build it, it says:"WebApplication4.Membership" does not contain a definition for "GetUserNameByEmail"

My connection string is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication4-20131005165648;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication4-20131005165648.mdf"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="aspnet_WebApplication4_20131005165648ConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication4-20131005165648;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: A possible solution could be to run the ASP.NET SQL Registration tool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=VS.100).aspx.  Then in your database, you should see a number of tables whose names start with the prefix aspnet_.

Comment: I don't see any reference or usage of linq to SQL in this code?

Comment: I have done that already. But it does not help fix it. A wired thing is that there is no problem if I create this in VS2010 @aspiring.algorist

Comment: That is because It already gets this error before any linq usage.The error pops up immediately after I set up the linq to sql.@AndrewCounts

Comment: @user2827614: I'm assuming all your tables are in SQL Server. If that's the case, what happens when you remove "AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication4-20131005165648.mdf" from DefaultConnection?

Comment: Actually I am using SQL Express in this case, which is the default setting in VS2012. And I have also tried to use SQL Server by modifying the connection string. Got the same result. Then I even tried to reinstall VS2012. Still not working. You know, the wired thing is that I can see method over there checking from the object explorer, but cannot use.@aspiring.algorist